# Inline CSS in Broccoli / Ember

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

Ember-cli builds four files: app.css, app.js, vendor.css and vendor.js.

How to merge those into single JS file?

That is required so all resources are loaded in single script to minimise number of requests.

UPDATE: this is the same functionality i'm after but in webpack https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html

Comment: A good option will be using **http/2**

Comment: I don't know anything about the technology you are using, but I found you can install a plugin named ember-cli-concat. Can it helps you?

Comment: @JeremyCochoy ember-cli-concat as far is I can see only solves half of the problem, merging from 4 file to 2.